# How to change validation rules depending on which post button you use?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have an ASP.NET MVC form, which is intended for processing a queue of items.  The user looks at the item and clicks either "Approve" or "Reject", both of which post to the same URL, just using a different "action" value, i.e.

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Approve" />
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Reject" />
```

and in the controller:

```
public ActionResult ReviewItem(MyModel mm, string action) { ... }
```

Now for the "Reject" action I want to force the user to include a rejection message.  So I want to have a validator next to the Rejection Message textbox - but it should obviously only be mandatory if the user clicks "Reject".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use jquery click function to check if rejection message is null and accordingly return false from that click funtion

Comment: @NitinVarpe, you want to put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('input[name=action]').click(function(){

   if($(this).val()=="Reject" && $('#rejmessage').val()=="")
    {
      alert('Please specify reason');
      return false;
     }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/X28XQ/)